# is this circuit board usable

Tags: power, board

[image]I was carrying out a modification on an xbox 360 controller and there were 3 spots I needed to solder wires to. The first two went well. However, I had a problem with the third.

Each spot I was soldering to already had solder on it. The first two wires went onto the board no problem, but with the third one, all the solder seemed to stick to the iron and leaving a little brown circle with a tint of black around on the board. No solder will stick to the circle which is the point where my wire needs to go. Any advice?

Comment: You may have destroyed the pad/? the wires were connected to. Can you post a clear photo of the problem area?

Comment: If you still have it, look at the blob of solder that removed with the iron. I think you will probably find your solder pad stuck to that (as EM Fields has suggested). That's how all of the solder seemed to remove with the iron. You may be able to scrape a little of the solder-mask from the broken trace and solder a very small wire to that. A microscope would help.

Comment: It could be that the third pad is a ground via and would take a lot more heat to get the solder to flow onto it.  Picture needed.  Edit your question and press the little picture icon above the editor.

Comment: It would help if the picture was a) in focus, and b) close up.

Comment: It's very hard to tell from the out-of-focus picture, but it looks like the pad is indeed missing. You may be able to fit a tiny wire into the hole at the center of the (missing?) pad. Either try wicking the solder out of the hole first or melting it with a soldering iron with a tiny drop of solder on it. Then try inserting the wire into the hole. Depending on the hole size you may be able to use AWG 30 (wire-wrap) wire. If that is too big, maybe a small strand from some finely stranded wire.

Comment: Maybe try tracing the track back to another pad you could use instead.

Comment: If there is a trace that was broken when the pad lifted, that will need to be re-connected, possibly by following it to another pad as Majenko has suggested. Either way, you might also try locating the corresponding pad on the other side of the board and connecting to that as that was connected to the original pad through the plated-through hole. Note you likely have 2 connections to make. One to repair a probable broken trace when the pad came off, and one to add your wire.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer without a picture, but I suspect the brown is flux on top of a copper pad. In which case:

- clean old flux with a slightly damp cloth, then dry
- apply new flux with flux pen
- solder as normal

If you don't have a flux pen, you can try to tin the pad by heating it for a couple of seconds with the iron and then applying flux-cored solder (usually electronics solder is flux-cored).

Don't sand it, this isn't a pipe, you run a risk of destroying the pad.

Comment: How to I upload a picture